# Expectation Of Number Of Dice Rolls

Tags: probability, expectation

I was asked the following question on a practice test:

> If two dice are rolled until their sum is seven, or they have been rolled twice, let the random variable `N` be equal to the number of rolls. Find the expectation of `N`.
>
> a)$\frac{7}{2}$
>   b)$\frac{5}{12}$
>   c)$\frac{11}{6}$
>   d)$\frac{5}{6}$
>   e)$\frac{5}{36}$

Right away you can kind of tell that `c` must be the solution because intuitively the expectation should be close to but less than $2$, but I did the calculation anyway.

I thought about it this way. The probability that the number of rolls is $1$ is equal to the probability that the sum of the dice is equal to $7$ on the first roll, which is $\frac{7}{36}$. Then, since we can have no more than $2$ rolls, the probability that the number of rolls is $2$ must be $\frac{29}{36}$. In other words,

$$P(N=1)=\frac{7}{36}$$
$$P(N=2)=\frac{29}{36}$$

So then the expectation of $N$ is

$$
E[N]=1\times\frac{7}{36}+2\times\frac{29}{36}
    =\frac{65}{36}
$$

This is freakishly close to the intuitive answer, `c`, but not quite right. Did I make a mistake, or did the test writer just forget to say they just wanted to the closest solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right in everything except that there are only 6 ways to roll a 7.

Comment: Ha! Oh my word, of course it would be something like that that I would get puzzled over. Thanks :)